# After upgrade to ub 14.04

Tags: upgrade

I want to free disk space. So I want to remove the files associated with ub 12.04 LTS and the many upgrades over the last 2 years. I have upgraded to ub 14.04 and it works extremely well. Many GBs could be freed up if I can remove / delete the older files.

I use and love ubuntu dual boot [win7 ultimate and ubuntu 14.04, but really can not use command line, UNLESS I CAN COPY AND PASTE EACH LINE OF CODE INTO TERMINAL, LINE BY LINE.

Please help !!!!

My 256 gb ssd is in 4 partitions. 50gb win7, 35gb ext4 ub 14.04, 2 gb swap file, 147 gb ntfs for MY FILES & INFO.

My ext4 partition has only 7gb free. I keep all my files on the Files partition. 147gb.

thanks, Kye

Mark, I moved 2 gb to non ub partition, THANK YOU.

bcbc, paul@U6910p-2:~$ ls /boot/vmlinuz-*
/boot/vmlinuz-3.0.0-12-generic   /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-34-generic
/boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-33-generic  /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-67-generi

I assume I can use Synaptic Package Mgr and possibly remove 3.13.0-34, I WILL NOT UNTIL I SEE YOUR SUGGESTION. THANK YOU.

Comment: What files specificity do you want to delete ? the installer should of cleaned up after the upgrade

Comment: Check things like the trash and your downloads folder to save some space

Comment: How many kernels do you have? Either run `ls /boot/vmlinuz-* | wc -l` from a terminal, or browse to your `/boot` folder in Nautilus and count them

Comment: Mark, I moved 2 gb to non ub partition, THANK YOU.

bcbc, paul@U6910p-2:~$ ls /boot/vmlinuz-* /boot/vmlinuz-3.0.0-12-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-34-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-33-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-67-generi

I assume I can use Synaptic Package Mgr and possibly remove 3.13.0-34, I WILL NOT UNTIL I SEE YOUR SUGGESTION. THANK YOU.

Comment: HELP,I still want to delete more of the updates and old os. Ubunutu partition with NO personal files is 25gb, too much. There must be something to delete. I do not know how to use Synaptic Packagae mgr. ANY SUGGESTIONS. Want to delete unnecessary files and old updates. thanks Kye

Comment: That's not too many kernels. You can save a couple of hundred MB per kernel. Try running `baobab` (Disk usage analyzer) that should tell you where the 25GB lies. PS add @bcbc in your comment if you want me to be notified.